# Constructing DFA - Criteria / Multiple solutions

Tags: logic, automata, regular-language, finite-automata

I'm currently studying for my logic exam, and looking into examples on DFA construction.

Assume the alphabet is {a, b}, and the language to be constructed is defined as follows:

```
{w | w has at least three a's}
```

All models solutions I have come across look like the following:

[image]

However, is this the only solution for the aforementioned language? For instance, would we still have a valid DFA if we omitted some of the b-transitions, as in the following case:

[image]

After all, the language would still consist of "at least three a's". However, if the latter model is not valid, why is that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends to some extent on the terminology used in your course.  However a DFA, as I understand the term, must have exactly one transition from every state for each letter.  This is not the case in your second example so it is not a DFA.

Your second example is however an instance of a **non-deterministic finite automaton**.  You will quite likely prove in your course that NDFAs accept the same languages as DFAs.

And as to your first question, there is certainly not a unique solution.  Many DFAs (and NDFAs) can be constructed to accept the same language.  To give a simple example, modify your DFA as follows: make the transition $b$ from $A$ go to a new non-accepting state $E$; from $E$ there are transitions $a$ to $B$ and $b$ to $E$.

Comment: I don't see anything nondeterministic in the second example. It is not uncommon for a DFA formalism to specify that the automaton implicitly rejects if it ends up a state with no applicable transition.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Presumably we are using different terminology.  I do not know what terminology is used in the OP's course.

Answer (score 1):

The language the automaton accepts is supposed to consist of **all strings** that contain at least three `a`s -- not only some of them.

The second of the automata you show fails to accept `baaa` -- there's no transition that will match the initial `b`.

Since the language accepted by the second automata does not include `baaa` and `baaa` is a string that contains at least three `a`, the language accepted by the automaton is not the language it's supposed to accept.